# Assign text from JTextField to File after user provides string

Tags: java, swing

My program is designed to be able to read a file, search within a file, and write to a file (each with a corresponding JButton) - depending on user input. It was initially a console app, but now I'm working on a GUI for it (using SWING). The issue I'm having is that the file (string format) the user specifies (types in JTextField) is read into the "targetFile" variable before the user provides input - resulting in a null value.

I want the program to wait until after the user clicks the desired button to read the string into the "targetFile" variable.

Here's the minimum code for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public class SimpleDBGUI {
static File targetFile;     //Declare File var to be used in methods below for holding user's desired file

public void mainWindow(){

    //Create main window for Program
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Simple Data Base");     //Init frame
    mainWindow.setSize(500, 180);       //Set frame size
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);        //Make frame visible

    //Create panel for the main window of the GUI
    JPanel simpleGUI = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbCons = new GridBagConstraints();
    mainWindow.getContentPane().add(simpleGUI);         //Adds JPanel container to the ContentPane of the JFrame

    //Create button linking to read function
    JButton readButton = new JButton("Read");       //Init button, and give text
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 2;
    gbCons.weightx = .1;
    readButton.setActionCommand("Read");
    readButton.addActionListener( new ButtonClickListener());
    simpleGUI.add(readButton, gbCons);      //Adds the "Read" button to the JPanel

    //Create TextField for user to input a desired file
    JTextField sdbTarget = new JTextField();
    gbCons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbCons.gridx = 0;
    gbCons.gridy = 1;
    gbCons.gridwidth = 3;
    simpleGUI.add(sdbTarget, gbCons);               //Adds TextField to GUI
    targetFile = new File(sdbTarget.getText());     //Writes input string to a File var, works but out of time resulting in null value
}

    public class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener{         //Sets the EventListener for every function

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            String function = event.getActionCommand();                                 //Reads the ActionCommand into a string for use in performing desired function
            if( function.equals("Read")){                                               //Read function
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();                                 //For the GUI version, supposed to open "targetFile" upon readButtonClick
                try {
                    desktop.open(targetFile);                                           //Surrounded with Try/Catch because Java complains
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

I made a reference to this class in main since you can't use directly use main to create a GUI. The null value returned by the line "targetFile = new File()" causes an IllegalArgumentException, saying that my file does not exist.

I ran the code through a Debugger, stepping the whole way, and it worked flawlessly. When I ran it normally the aforementioned line doesn't give the user time to input a file path, or wait for the user to click the button, before trying to grab text (that doesn't yet exist) form the JTextField.

This is my initial stack-trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file:  doesn't exist.
at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:210)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:270)
at simpleDatabase.SimpleDBGUI$ButtonClickListener.actionPerformed(SimpleDBGUI.java:108)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

---

```
public class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener{         //Sets the EventListener for every function

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        File targetFile = new File(sdbTarget.getText());String function = event.getActionCommand();                                 //Reads the ActionCommand into a string for use in performing desired function
            if( function.equals("Read")){                                               //Read function
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();                                 //For the GUI version, supposed to open "targetFile" upon readButtonClick
                desktop.open(targetFile);
```

My current stack-trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at simpleDatabase.SimpleDBGUI$ButtonClickListener.actionPerformed(SimpleDBGUI.java:101)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: @VinceEmigh I didn't include the ButtonClickListeners becasue they work properly (click button Y, do thing Y). The FileWriter is for use with a different function of my program - I have a habit of instantiating my vars at the "top" of my methods/classes. The code I was intending to be focused on were the section for the JTextField, and the section for the "Read" function. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but these two parts are (or seem to be) what I'm having issues with.

Comment: You show a `JTextField`, but you don't show it actually being used anywhere. Where are you grabbing the text from the field? You also show irrelevant code (`Scanner` isn't used in the code you are showing). Keep ind mind, we cannot see what you see. It's best to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can actually reproduce the problem on their computers.

Comment: Are you getting an `Exception`? Can you show us the stack trace? which line has the exception?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I made a huge edit, showcasing the Read function and it's supporting code, nothing else. I do apologize for the previous version's incompleteness, I was trying to minimize the amount of digging required to solve the problem. Do you mind taking a look at the new version?

Comment: @SanjayManohar It was throwing an IllegalArgumentException (due to null value being returned), saying that my file doesn't exist (which it does).

Comment: You should have posted the stack trace then! It contains a lot of information.

Comment: @SanjayManohar What exactly is the "stack trace?" I'm relatively new to programming and this is my most ambitious project by far. Is it the series of red text in the Console that tells what exception was thrown and the multitudes of lines it was thrown on?

Comment: @JoshuaNapier The stacktrace is what prints to your console in red when an error occurs. Code executes on a ["stack"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation), and the stacktrace traces the execution up to where the error occured, what line it occured on (if you have access to the code), as well as which thread encountered the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create `targetFile` inside the listener.

You want to grab the text when the user presses a button. That means `sdbTarget.getText()` must be called when the button is pressed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    File file = new File(sdbTarget.getText());

    //...
}
```

You currently call it shortly after creating the components, which is why it returns an empty `String`.

---

You could use a lambda expression for your `ActionListener` if you're using Java 8+:

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {

});
```

Although what you have now is fine, if you'd rather keep the code separate.

`JTextField` also supports `ActionListener`. It fires an event when the user presses Enter while the field is in focus.

Comment: What do I do about it not being resolved to a type? Every time I do one of IntelliSense's proposed fixes, it tries to declare/ instantiate the JTextField as an "AbstractButton."

Comment: @JoshuaNapier What isn't being resolved to a type? Did you import everything?

Comment: And throws a NullPointerReference Exception when I run it.

Comment: @JoshuaNapier That info alone doesn't really help me. Where is the `NullPointerException` occuring? What's the stacktrace?

Comment: When I instantiate my target file within my Listener class it doesn't resolve. What would I need to import, and where?

Comment: @JoshuaNapier Edit your current code into the question (under your current question, using ____ to separate them) so I can see what you have. My guess is you created a new `file` variable like in my answer, but are still trying to use `targetFile`. Simply initialize `targetFile` in your listener instead of creating a new variable.

Comment: I've tried both, got the same result. Java can't/ won't resolve "sdbTarget" to a type. I posted the two pieces immediately within the vicinity of the edit you proposed

Comment: @JoshuaNapier Declare your `JTextField` in the field so your button class can access it

Comment: This is what I have immediately after my method is created:      File targetFile = sdbTarget.getText();

Comment: Can you post the line I should type, in verbatim, so that I can see exactly what I need to do?

Comment: @JoshuaNapier Change `JTextField sdbTarget = new JTextField();` to `sdbTarget = new JTextField();`, then add `static JTextField sdbTarget;` under `static File targetFile;`

Comment: It worked! Thank You! So the issue I was having was that I didn't declare my JTextField globally?

Comment: @JoshuaNapier Yup, that was the second issue you were having. The first one was due to not calling `getText()` in the listener, and instead attempting to grab the text as soon as the field is created